# Laravel SAML2 ACS redirecting to HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, saml-2.0

We have a demo site set up using laravel-saml2 and onelogin/php-saml. The problem we're having is that the /saml/acs route is redirecting everything to http instead of https. Any ideas where in the settings this could be or any other reasons this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to review lavarel routes but also the endpoints defined at [saml2_settings.php](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/blob/master/src/config/saml2_settings.php), based on those endpoints the metadata XML is generated.

Review that the SP metadata contains https endpoints and you registered that on the IdP side. And check that IdP endpoints are also https.